# How to find an exe in $PATH using Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I'm writing a C++ program using the Boost libraries. I need to be able to find the full path of an executable, given only the name. This would be the equivalent of the Unix shell's `which` utility, Windows' `where`, or Python's `shutil.which`.

Is there a way of doing this? I could of course write my own, by iterating over the PATH environment variable, but for portability I'd need to consider things like splitting on `:` or `;`, etc, and if there's a pre-written (and tested!) routine for this I'd prefer to use it.

Comment: Well, ultimately you're going to need to consider the specifics of the shell you're on, so why don't you just use the tool provided by that shell *boggle*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing that directly implements this in boost. You could either:

1. Read contents of `PATH` with [`getenv()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv), use [Boost File System](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) to deal with the paths in a portable manner, and handle the multi-path splitting manually - doesn't seem like the number of split characters could be insane, just a few alternatives
2. [invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix) your shell's existing `which` program (or variant thereof)
3. invoke a simple python program calling `shutil.which`, e.g. `system("python -c \"import shutil; shutil.which('ls');\"")`

Comment: OK, fair enough. It's a bit of a shame there's nothing available, but as you say it's not a disaster to write it myself. I don't want to start shelling out to other programs, as the reason I'm writing this application in C++ is performance and low footprint, and calling subprocesses would kill that (at that point I probably might as well write the whole thing in Python anyway...)

Comment: Mhm, OK. From a performance POV it may be an overkill to write this type of thing in C++; and also a bit counter-productive; `python` has much better support for system level tasks IMHO. I don't know your context, but you could presumably just load all the path information at program startup, which would take very little time in any language

Answer (score 0):

"Write my own" is how this is typically done. While this might've been a bear in C, with C++ and its rich `std::string` class this becomes a no-brainer. Don't even need Boost. This would be a typical homework assignment in introductory C++ courses:

```
std::string s=getenv("PATH");

const char sep=':';  // Or use ';', if you feel like it.

auto b=s.begin(), e=s.end();

while (b != e)
{
    if (*b == sep)
    {
        ++b;
        continue;
    }

    auto p=b;
    b=std::find(b, e, sep);

    auto check=std::string(p, b) + "/" + filename;

    if (access(filename.c_str(), X_OK) == 0)
    {
          // Found it. Insert code here.
    }
}
```

This is such a non-issue, it would've probably been faster to just knock this out, then try to find some library function, somewhere, that does the same thing.

Comment: Sure, except this type of code is not exactly portable when working with filesystems: `auto check=std::string(p, b) + "/" + filename;` (i.e. the hardcoded `/`) and is the type of mistake you open yourself to when doing it yourself IMHO; the OP is not asking how to do it, but how to do it in a portable manner, which I think makes sense;

Comment: Also, `std::string`, on Windows at least, doesn't support the full Unicode character set, which the filesystem does. So a portable version would need to do encoding conversions, or use wstring. Basically, it's simple enough in a "works for me" context, not so much for something that needs to work for a lot of users...